# arch linux doesn't boot after windows 11 fresh install in another disk

Tags: arch-linux

I have an HD Nvme2 with arch linux system installed. Boot ok.
I've replace this hd with another then I've done a fresh install of windows11 (needed for a friend).
When I restore my arch linux default hd, no boot option was made and laptop goes in bios mode...I think I've reset some cmos with win11 installation...

There is a way to fix my arch disk without reinstall arch os?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
NVRAM was overwrite by Windows11.
So, boot an usb stick with arch iso live and followed this steps:

- mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt (root part on mnt)
- mkdir /mnt/boot
- mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
- mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi (efi part on /mnt/boot/efi)
- arch-chroot /mnt (chroot in the system)
- follow [grub wiki 2.1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB) to reinstall grub

now laptop NVRAM was correctly written with arch os system entry and boot correctly.
Remember to adjust paths accordingly with hw and sw of your system.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the windows installation removed the EFI entry of Arch Linux. No need for a full reinstall, just use a live system to reinstall GRUB.

This page in the Debian wiki could help: https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall

Comment: thanks a lot I will try. Before to do this kind of reinstall..it's possible to connect the disk with windows11 in usb 3.2 and update grub also with the windows system in usb drive? The purpose is to have the default OS with arch, but only if it is necessary for my friend boot up laptop in windows11 via usb only if it's attached.

Comment: You can perform `update-grub` (or whatever is equivalent on arch) with OS prober to find the windows boot loader. However I'm not sure how it would handle it being on a USB port. I think you better rely on the firmware boot menu in this case.